# PyPDF2 not loading in visual studio code

Tags: python, anaconda, pypdf

I am using visual studio code via Anaconda. I installed PyPDF2 in Anaconda's command via:

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

However, I can't import it from VSC. I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2'
```

Even though I can import it in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem. it was because of Python 3.8.2. using a previous version will make things work.